# React Google Analytics Pageview showing without any code

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I've implemented google analytics into a react app. The problem is that it just shows the page title upon every page view. What's really strange is that when I disable the code to update upon page change, it still registers each url change as a new pageview in Google Analytics (With the same page title as always). This is navigating to pages using the react-router-dom, not hard refreshed, but the pageviews are still showing in GA!

Here's the code I'm using

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState, createContext } from "react";

export const GoogleAnalyticsContext = createContext(null);

function GoogleAnalyticsProvider({children}) {
  const [gaInitialized, setGaInitialized] = useState(false);
  const [gaTrackingCode, setGaTrackingCode] = useState();
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    //Fetch tracking code
    setGaTrackingCode('[my tracking code]')
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    if (gaTrackingCode) {
      console.log("Updating script");
      const script1 = document.createElement('script');
      script1.async = true;
      script1.src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${gaTrackingCode}`
      document.body.appendChild(script1);

      const script2 = document.createElement('script');
      script2.async = true;
      script2.text = `
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){window.dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        window.gtag = gtag;
        gtag('js', new Date());
      
        gtag('config', '${gaTrackingCode}', {
          cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None;Secure'
        });  
      `
      document.body.appendChild(script2);
      setGaInitialized(true);
    }
  }, [gaTrackingCode])

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (gaInitialized) {
  //     window.gtag('config', gaTrackingCode, {
  //       page_title: location.pathname + location.search,
  //       page_page: location.pathname + location.search
  //     })
  //   }
  // }, [gaInitialized, location])

  const store = {
    gaInitialized
  }

  return <GoogleAnalyticsContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</GoogleAnalyticsContext.Provider>
}

export default GoogleAnalyticsProvider
```

Notice the commented out part. It's still registering new pageviews even with that commented out.

I'd wonder if Google has implemented some new feature, if it weren't for the fact that I've got the exact same setup running in a different environment, and this doesn't happen, and the pageviews work correctly (with the commented out code uncommented)

Edit: I've checked with console.log, and the initialization script is only being called once.

Edit2: I'm using a workaround. I can send events successfully, so I'm sending all the pageviews as events.